# Need to add onclick javascript at backend of my wordpress site

Tags: wp-query

I don't know much about coding as I am not a developer. I have owned a WordPress blog and I want to track the number of users has submitted the contact form. As it does not redirect to Thankyou page, so my Goal value will always show zero in analytics, even the users are filling the contact us form. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are many different contact form plugins. Some of them will store the submitted forms in the WordPress backend. This makes it easy to track the number of submitted forms.

An example of a plugin that stores the responses is [Happy Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/happyforms/). Of course there are many others.

I hope this addresses your request.

Comment: Great, glad that it was helpful :)